# How can I add multiple values of checkboxes in database

Tags: c#

I am trying to provide "1" value when the checkbox is checked and "0" when it's not checked.

[image]

But whenever I select some of the checkboxes and try to insert on the database, automatically, all the checkboxes are selected and I get all the columns in databases with "1" value. I am using the Microsoft SQL server 2014.

This is the image of my form and columns in my database:

[image: This is the image of my form and columns in my database]

```
"Insert into UserPrivl values ('" + lboUsers.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', '" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkCreateComp.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkSaveAs.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkAddControl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditControl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteControl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteControl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkAddIndi.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditIndi.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteIndi.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkPandLDef.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkBSDef.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkBudgetInfo.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewJournal.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditJournal.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteJournal.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','0','0','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewReceipt.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditReceipt.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteReceipt.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','0','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewPayment.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditPayment.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeletePayment.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','0','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewBankR.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditBankR.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteBankR.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewBankP.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','"
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditBankP.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteBankP.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewWithdrawl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditWithdrawl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteWithdrawl.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','0','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkNewDeposit.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditDeposit.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteDeposit.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','0','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDaybook.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkJournalExplorer.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','0','0','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkStockGroup.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkAddStock.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditStock.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteStock.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkAddStockTran.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkEditStockTran.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkDeleteStockTran.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkTranReport.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkStockReport.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkSalesReport.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkPurchaseReport.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkChart.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkControlStat.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkTrialBal.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkBalanceUnderCon.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkVoucher.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkIndiStat.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkFinancialStat.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkBalList.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkUserReport.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkGraph.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkSearch.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkMissing.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkAudit.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "','" 
    + (Convert.ToBoolean(chkSysSet.Checked = true) ? "1" : "0") + "')");
```

Comment: Replace `=` with `==` in ternary operator

Comment: or skip all equal signs like this `Convert.ToBoolean(chkBalList.Checked)`

Comment: thanks, bro appreciate ur help

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will always get value 1 inserted to the table because `chkCreateComp.Checked = true` will evaluate to `true` always
Change this to conditional equals to operator.. (==)